# One Step from Happiness --all my inputs give correct output but still it says wrong answer

Tags: c

I'm trying to do [Timus Online Judge question #1493, "One Step from Happiness"](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?num=1493&locale=en):

> Vova bought a ticket in a tram of the 13th route and counted the sums of the first three and the last three digits of the ticket's number (the number has six digits). It turned out that the sums differed by one exactly. "I'm one step from happiness," Vova thought, "either the previous or the next ticket is lucky." Is he right?
>
> **Input**
>
> The input contains the number of the ticket. The number consists of six digits, some of which can be zeros. It is guaranteed that Vova counted correctly, i.e., that the sum of the first three digits differs from the sum of the last three digits by one exactly.
>
> **Output**
>
> Output "Yes" if Vova is right and "No" otherwise.
>
> **Samples**
>
> ```
>   input      output
> --------------------
>  715068      Yes
>  445219      No
>  012200      Yes
> ```
>
> **Hint**
>
> All tram tickets have exactly six digits. A ticket is considered lucky if the sum of its first three digits equals the sum of its last three digits.

Here is my code in Visual C(2010) format.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() 
{
  int arr[5],arr1[5],arr2[5],i,a=0,b=0,n,x=0,y=0;
  printf("Enter number");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  x=n+1;
  y=n-1;
  while(n>0)
    {
      for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
    {
      arr[i]=n%10;
      n=n/10;
    }
    }

  a=( arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]);
  b=(arr[3]+arr[4]+arr[5]);

  if((a-b==1)||(a-b==-1))
    {
      while(x>0)
    {
      for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
        {
          arr1[i]=x%10;
          x=x/10;
        }
    }
      while(y>0)
    {
      for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
        {
          arr2[i]=y%10;
          y=y/10;
        }
    }
      if ((arr1[0]+arr1[1]+arr1[2]==arr1[3]+arr1[4]+arr1[5]) ||
          (arr2[0]+arr2[1]+arr2[2]==arr2[3]+arr2[4]+arr2[5]))
    { printf("Yes");}
      else
    { printf("No");}
    }
  else
    {
      printf("No");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

The above code is the one I submitted and received a wrong answer in Timus Online Judge. The format in which it was submitted was Visual C (2010). I use Dev-C++ on my computer, so the code I run on my computer is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> 

 main() 
{
  int arr[5],arr1[5],arr2[5],i,a=0,b=0,n,x=0,y=0;
  printf("Enter number");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  x=n+1;
  y=n-1;
  while(n>0)
    {
      for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
    {
      arr[i]=n%10;
      n=n/10;
    }
    }

  a=( arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]);
  b=(arr[3]+arr[4]+arr[5]);

  if((a-b==1)||(a-b==-1))
    {
      while(x>0)
    {
      for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
        {
          arr1[i]=x%10;
          x=x/10;
        }
    }
      while(y>0)
    {
      for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
        {
          arr2[i]=y%10;
          y=y/10;
        }
    }
      if ((arr1[0]+arr1[1]+arr1[2]==arr1[3]+arr1[4]+arr1[5]) ||
          (arr2[0]+arr2[1]+arr2[2]==arr2[3]+arr2[4]+arr2[5]))
    { printf("Yes");}
      else
    { printf("No");}
    }
  else
    {
      printf("No");
    }
  getch();
}
```

I received no compilation errors. The code ran perfectly on my Dev-C++ compiler and also gave me correct output. The problem is when I submit this code in the Visual C format and they tell me it is a wrong answer.

Comment: could you atleast format it correctly before posting?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Are you sure that `int arr[5]` is the best way to declare an array of six integers?

Comment: Why are you printing `"\nYes"` and `"\nNo"`? The problem description says to print `"Yes"` or `"No"`.

Comment: @hobbs: because he's on a Windows machine (`<conio.h>`) and the answer appears and when he hits return for `getch()` to read, that ends the line.  It's partly because windows vanish, I believe, if you don't make them hang around like that...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's also a perfectly good reason for the online judge to say that all of the output is wrong, since it doesn't meet the spec :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  It's great that you told us what you're trying to do, and included your code.  But you also need to tell us what the code is doing incorrectly.  Does it compile?  If not, what is the error message?  If it compiles, what happens when you run it?  Does it crash?  Does it give incorrect output?  Please edit your post to include these details, including the compiler error, or crash report, or incorrect output, or whatever else appears in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise states:

```
Output "Yes" if Vova is right and "No" otherwise.
```

Your program prints `Enter number`, which the exercise does not ask for. Try to remove that.

Also, for your own and our sanity, I strongly recommend you format your program better. Finding errors is much easier in a beautiful, well-formatted program. For tips on how to make your code more readable and clean, you can head over to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).